# Lightbox2 theming

Tags: theming, javascript

Can anyone advice me on how to theme the lightbox popup?

I have a design where the close and image navigation bottons have to be repositioned from their default location.

Please help!?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a new CSS file (or add lines to your existing file) and overwrite the rules that are applied to the lightbox. Unfortunately we cannot help you any further if you don't give more information. Can you give an online test case and preferably an image of what you are trying to achieve?